# How to find specific value or string in txt file and put in table in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, itext

I want to find specific value or string in .txt file and put it in Jtable or iText output .

like this:

txt data:

```
R17 12, 1
R17 12, 2
R17 12, 3
R17 12, 4
R15 12, 5
R17 12, 6
R15 12, 7
R15 12, 8
R12 12, 9
R15 12, 10
R15 13, 1
R17 13, 2
R15 13, 3
R15 13, 4
R17 13, 5
R15 13, 6
R15 13, 7
R15 13, 8
R15 13, 9
R15 13, 10
```

and i want table output like this:

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: Before you even get to the UI, you will want to generate some kind of model which would provide you with a virtual view of what you are trying to achieve, this will make wrapping the UI around much, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You'll need to parse the .txt file. To do that you'll use a Scanner ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Steps:

- Set the scanner to "read" from your file
- Parse each line at once from your file
- Split each line in parts to get the individual values that you want
- Assign each of that, previously splited, values to the "fields" of the table

  ```
  File fileExample = new File("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE.txt");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileExample);

  String[] parts = null;

  while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

     String line = input.nextLine();
     parts = line.split("\\s");  //parse the line by spaces

     //From now on I cant help you. 
     You need to build the Table and assign the values to it. 
  }
  ```

To build the table you just use the Swing library. Link here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/.

Hope you get some ideas from this. 
The code is not compiled. It's just some ideas.

Comment: and how to put it in table? this is my main problem

Comment: @Bahador I am assuming that you have read the documentation. For instance: [Questions and Answers about tables](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/tables). Seems like you want to [publish data](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/publish-database). Can you please explain what was unclear in that documentation so that we can improve it?